# What does the pm2 default logrotate files settings mean?

Tags: node.js, linux, tar, pm2, logrotate

I am currently working on an app that creates a lot of large log files. And so in order to manage these I would like to just restart the app at midnight, compress the log file it left behind, and start a new log file with the current date, so the log folder might look like this:

```
latest.log
2022-10-22_00:00:00.log.tar.gz
2022-10-21_00:00:00.log.tar.gz
2022-10-20_00:00:00.log.tar.gz
2022-10-19_00:00:00.log.tar.gz
```

PM2 promises to be able to do this using this module:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2-logrotate
But it seems to have a nasty reputation:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71852170/2741831

So I was ready to give up when I found that pm2 has a native function that is confusingly also called logrotate:

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/#Setting%20up%20a%20native%20logrotate
Section native logrotate

Which generates a config file that looks like this:

```
/home/user/.pm2/pm2.log /home/user/.pm2/logs/*.log {
        rotate 12
        weekly
        missingok
        notifempty
        compress
        delaycompress
        create 0640 user user
}
```

which is not documented anywhere so I have no idea what it is or how it works, although it appears to be able to compress log files, which is nice.
It doesn't even say if I have to setup a crontab for it or not.

So heres my questions:

- can I use pm2 native logrotate to setup a system like described above?
- what does the config files and especially the path at the top mean?
- will pm2-logrotate itself or do I need to setup a crontab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, all this command does is generate a config file for the Redhat logrotate utility. So I guess just use that

Answer (score 1):

As @user2741831 say it use the native logrotate of your linux system.

> - The first line indicates that the directives inside the block apply to
>   all logs inside /home/user/.pm2/logs/*.log:
> - **weekly** means that the tool will attempt to rotate the logs on a weekly basis. Other possible values are hourly, daily and monthly.
> - **rotate 12** indicates that only 12 rotated logs should be kept. Thus, the oldest file will be removed on the fourth subsequent run.
> - **missingok** If the log file is missing, go on to the next one without issuing an error message.
> - **compress** and **delaycompress** are used to tell that all rotated logs, with the exception of the most recent one, should be compressed.

You can find some explanation on this  [link](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/logrotate/logrotate.conf.5.en.html) for Debian